# Parsing type "C" column for specific value using a given pattern in kdb+

Tags: kdb

Consider a column of type `C` in a kdb+ table that contains a message as follows:

`They evaulated VAR_1(0.1)*VAR_2(0.2)*VAR_3(0.3)*VAR(1.1) > ? a*b`

The objective is to look for the value specifically within `VAR`'s parenthesis. Given the above example, the expectation is to return `1.1`.

Here is my current unsuccessful attempt:

`parseMsg:{l:{"VAR(" vs x} each ") >" vs x; l2:{x where {x[0] like "*VAR*"} each x} l1; "F"$12[0][1]};`

I would then use the above to call `select parseMsg each msg from tbl`. While this runs, I'm not yet able to get the value within.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version works for me when you fix the typos:

```
t:([]msg:("They evaulated VAR_1(0.1)*VAR_2(0.2)*VAR_3(0.3)*VAR(1.1) > ? a*b";"They evaulated VAR_1(0.1)*VAR_2(0.2)*VAR_3(0.3)*VAR(22.22) > ? a*b"));

parseMsg:{l:{"VAR(" vs x} each ") >" vs x; l2:{x where {x[0] like "*VAR*"} each x} l; "F"$l2[0][1]};

q)select parseMsg each msg from t
msg
-----
1.1
22.22
```

You might also be able to use the `0:` key-value shortcut https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#key-value-pairs

```
q)select{"F"$((!)."S()"0:x)`$"*VAR"}each msg from t
msg
-----
1.1
22.22
```